# How to Store Name of element into list after getting a count of parent element present on webpage

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

> I've my test written in Robot Framework to get a count of all elements present on the webpage with the store name(Charcoal Eats).
>
> Now I want to store the name of item ( Chicken Seekh Pav Wow (Set of 2) ) associated with that store name
> How should I read the food item names and store them into a list.
> please refer to the image for clarity of the store name and item name

[image: Store name and Food item name]

Below is my test for counting and storing the store name.

```
${xpath}=   Set Variable    //div[contains(@class, '_2o8fn') and text()='Charcoal Eats']                
${count}=   Get Matching Xpath Count    ${xpath}                
${names}=   Create List                 
FOR ${i}    IN RANGE    1   ${count} + 1        
\   ${name}=    Get Text    xpath=(${xpath})            
\   Append To List  ${names}    ${name}
```

[image: Code result]
Thank You!

Comment: Can you show what your current code produce (with what it does versus what you expected)?

Comment: Have updated my question with the result of my current code, now after the store name is found on page,  i need to write a code to read the Item name - "chicken seekh pav wow (set of 2)" associated with the store name (charcoal Eats) and store this item name into a list. Currently this page has got only 1 item with store name - Charcoal eats , there can be multiple aswell.